# How do use Property(string notVisiblePropertyOrFieldName, Action<IPropertyMapper> mapping) for ComposedId?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to map something in code.

this works fine:

```
ComposedId(cm =>
               {
                   cm.Property(x => x.Column1);
                   cm.Property(x => x.Column2);
               });
```

which is function

```
void Property<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TContainer, TProperty>> property);
```

However, I'm trying to make it more dynamic, with

```
void Property(string notVisiblePropertyOrFieldName, Action<IPropertyMapper> mapping)
```

I tried setting about every option, like so:

```
ComposedId(cm =>
               {
                       cm.Property("Column1", a =>
                                                   {
                                                       a.Access(Accessor.Property);
                                                       a.Column("Column1");
                                                       a.Generated(PropertyGeneration.Never);
                                                       a.Index("Column1");
                                                       a.Insert(true);
                                                       a.Lazy(false);
                                                       a.NotNullable(true);
                                                       a.Update(true);
                                                       a.Unique(false);
                                                       a.Type(NHibernateUtil.Int32);
                                                       a.Length(int.MaxValue);
                                                       a.Scale(0);
                                                   });
                   }
               });
```

And similar for Column2, but nothing seems to work.
it simply ignores my ComposedId, I assume nhibernate does not recognize it as a proper identifier, because it tries to an "Id" column as identifier, which does not exist.

how am I suppose to create the Action mapping so that it does work?

Comment: Did you ever get this working.  Could you have a look at my similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47536695/cannot-use-nhibernate-code-mapping-for-a-private-field  +1.