# Cannot use NHibernate Code Mapping for a private field

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

What is the equivalent NHibernate Code Mapping for the following Fluent NHibernate code:

```
Map(x => x.Orders).Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
```

I have spent all afternoon trying to get this to work.  Here is my code so far:

```
public class Customer
{
    private readonly IList<Order> _orders = new List<Order>();
    public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders 
    {
        get { foreach (var order in _orders) yield return order; }
    }

    internal void AddOrder(Order order)
    {
        _orders.Add(order);
    }
}  

public class CustomerMap : ClassMapping<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        Id<Guid>(x => x.Id);

        Component(x => x.LastName, y =>
        {
            y.Property<string>(z => z.LastName);
        });

        Bag(x => x._orders, collectionMapping =>
        {
            collectionMapping.Table("CustomerOrders");
            collectionMapping.Cascade(Cascade.None);
            collectionMapping.Key(k => k.Column("CustomerId"));
        },
        map => map.ManyToMany(p => p.Column("OrderId")));
    }
}
```

This answers my question: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nhusers/wiH1DPGOhgU.  I have tried copying and pasting the code from my link (see below):

```
  this.Bag(
                    r => "privatefieldtomap",
                    map =>
                        {
                            map.Access(Access.Field);
                            map.Table("table");
                            map.Key(k => k.Column("foreignkey"));
                        },
                    r => r.Element(m => m.Column("columntomap")));
```

The error I get is: Bag cannot be inferred from the usage.

Comment: You cannot access a private field outside the class. See the comment in the forum: _using the method overloads that take delegates instead of those that take strings_

Comment: @Devio, then how do you do this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/361359/what-is-the-benefit-of-encapsulating-a-collection-inside-a-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options to map a non-visible field by code.

Here are some, please note that I haven't tested them yet as written, but should help you anyways:

```
// Option 1:
public class CustomerMap : ClassMapping<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        // ...

        Bag<Order>("_orders", collectionMapping =>
        {
            //...
        },
        map => map.ManyToMany(p => p.Column("OrderId")));
    }
}

// Option 2: No strings, but I'm not sure if this one would really work as is.
public class CustomerMap : ClassMapping<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        // ...

        Bag(x => x.Orders, collectionMapping =>
        {
            collectionMapping.Access(Accessor.Field),

            //...
        },
        map => map.ManyToMany(p => p.Column("OrderId")));
    }
}

// Option 3: No strings, but more convoluted.
public class Customer
{
    internal class PrivatePropertyAccessors
    {
        public static Expression<Func<Customer, IEnumerable<Order>>> OrdersProperty = c => c._orders;
    }

    private readonly IList<Order> _orders = new List<Order>();

    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders
    {
        get { foreach (var order in _orders) yield return order; }
    }
}

public class CustomerMap : ClassMapping<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        // ...

        Bag(Customer.PrivatePropertyAccessors.OrdersProperty, collectionMapping =>
        {
            //...
        },
        map => map.ManyToMany(p => p.Column("OrderId")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a naming strategy:

```
cfg.SetNamingStrategy(myStrategy);
```

Where `myStrategy` is an implementation of `INamingStrategy`.
See my blog post at https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/nhibernate-conventions

Comment: Thanks.  The blog post does not speak about private variables.  I cannot believe there is absolutely no documentation whatsoever for Mapping By Code.  Can you post some code as you did in the link in my question.  Thanks again.

Comment: I think you can use the same for properties... see the INamingStrategy definition here: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Cfg/INamingStrategy.cs.

Comment: Thanks.  I am new to NHibernate (from Entity Framework).  Could you post some code.  My research is telling me that I am only missing a few lines.  Thanks again.

Comment: Could you explain how the link in the question helps?